# Renault Clio 2 2001 1.6 K4M engine. Takes several tries to start engine if starts at all when idle for several hours

Tags: starting, renault, clio

As the title suggests. I already changed spark plugs and the fuel pump's pressure is 3.6 - 3.8 bar which is ok. When the engine starts works fine and if i stop it and then restart I'm successful on the first try, but when idle for several hours it will take 4 or 5 attempts of a few seconds each with the starter to get it on. However, like today, it did not start even after several attempts.

I'm puzzled as well as my mechanic! Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Check the fuel pressure over time. This sounds like you might have a leaking injector (or more than one!). Pressure should be stable for many hours. If it bleeds off through an injector over time, you could possibly be flooding that cylinder with fuel, which would make it hard to start.

Comment: Thank you @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2! I'll forward this to my mech.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 woulnd that make the car fail while functioning as well?

Comment: With a leaking injector, if the vehicle sits for only a short while, the engine will start right away because there won't be much fuel in the cylinder. If it sits for a while, the cylinder has a lot of fuel in it, which causes it to behave like it's flooded, which will make it hard to start if it will start at all. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to came late to this party ... but I will leave here my experience with the same model, engine and year. I had the same starting issues ... reading in a really old Spanish blog, somebody mentioned the **crankshaft sensor** ... we were really puzzled with my mechanic, when we find out that it was the solution to my starting issues ... we change it, and the engine started like a new one ... Hope this helps someone!